# find a number is between which range in a list of list

Tags: python

Need some python help, I have a list:

```
[[sql1, 1, 10], [sql2, 12, 16]...]
```

I want to know if 15 is in the sql2, please let me know in python the easy way.

I have tried in the loop.

Comment: Maybe what you wrote *is* the easy way; until you share it, one cannot say.

Comment: Do you mean that 15 is one of the two integers in the list that starts with `sql2`, or that 15 is between those two integers? Are you sure that the values of `sql1` and `sql2` etc. are different?

Comment: Please show your code and explain what difficulties you are having

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to give a few more details about your desired implementation, but this was too fun not to answer.

My answer assumes:

1. You want a list of the beginning strings (`index == 0`) of the sublists whose:
2. 2nd and 3rd elements contain `15` in the range of a (inclusive) and b (exclusive)

This is in Python 3.

```
>>> x = [['sql1', 1, 10], ['sql2', 12, 16]]
>>> [a for a, *b in x if 15 in range(*b)]
['sql2']
```

This also works with multiple matches:

```
>>> x = [['sql1', 1, 10], ['sql2', 12, 16], ['sql3', 15, 17]]
>>> [a for a, *b in x if 15 in range(*b)]
['sql2', 'sql3']
```

If you want to accept `'sql2'` and `15` as input and return a boolean:

```
>>> x = [['sql1', 1, 10], ['sql2', 12, 16]]
>>> check = 'sql2'
>>> n = 15
>>> any(a == check and n in range(*b) for a, *b in x)
True
```

Comment: List Comprehension is always fun! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

First, lest solve for the simplest solution and then look into making something generic out of it.

```
test_data = [['sql', 1, 10],['sql2', 12, 16, 15]]
print(15 in test_data[1]) # True
```

We can even generalize it into a function

```
def in_data(data_sets, data, check_in):
    for data_set in data_sets:
        if data in data_set:
            if check_in in data_set:
                return True
    return False
```

@Robᵩ pointed out a more elegant/compact solution that allows us to write:

```
def in_data(data_sets, data, check_in):
    return any(check_in in data_set for data_set in data_sets)
```

Comment: Or, using the `any()` builtin: `return any(check_in in data_set for data_set in data_sets)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ I like it! Thanks for showing this to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have hard coded the data to meet the question requirements but the
answer can be modified as required

```
my_list = [['sql1', 1, 10], ['sql2', 12, 16]]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
    if my_list[i][0] == 'sql1':
        if '15' in my_list[i][0]:
            print("found")
        else:
            print("not found")
```

Comment: It won't work in Python 2.7 - and OP did not state the version

Comment: @volcano; correct, since the version wasn't stated I went with 3.x

Comment: it's better to iterate over my_list directly: `for sublist in my_list: if sublist[0] ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ; indeed it is. Thank you for the tip.